# Click on multiple buttons to progress to next page

Tags: javascript, html

need some help. When I click the yellow tape on the page it disappears (granting access up the stairs. However I'm struggling to program it so that when all three are clicked, it progresses to the next page. Any help appreciated.

[image: image of webpage]

```js
var counter = 0;
function del1()
if (counter == 0) {
  {
    document.getElementById("img3").style.display = 'none';
    counter++;
  }
}

function del2()
if (counter == 1) {

  {
    document.getElementById("img4").style.display = 'none';
    counter++;
  }
}

function del3()
if (counter == 2) {

  {
    document.getElementById("img5").style.display = 'none';
    counter++;
  }
}

function win()
if (counter === 3) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timerem', rem);
  window.open('page2.html', "_self");
}
```

Comment: Your JS has many syntax issues. You need  ALL your functions to look like `function functionName() { code }`

Comment: oh dead @mplungjan I didn't even see that as I skimmed it. Good shout.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the pointer, is it logically correct?

Comment: I added a fix to your code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using delegation

Wrap the tape images in a div with id = stairs and give each of them a class of tape

Let me know if you must cut them in order

```js
const tapes = 3;
document.getElementById("stairs").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target; // whatever clicked in the div 
  if (tgt.className.contains("tape")) { // we clicked a tape
    tgt.className.add("hide"); // hide it
    const allSnipped = tgt.closest("div").querySelectorAll(".tape.hide").length === tapes; // count .hide's 
    if (allSnipped) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      sessionStorage.setItem('timerem', rem);
      location = 'page2.html';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

---

Your code fixed

```js
var counter = 0;

function del1() {
  if (counter == 0) {
    document.getElementById("img3").style.display = 'none';
    counter++;
  }
}

function del2() {
  if (counter == 1) {
    document.getElementById("img4").style.display = 'none';
    counter++;
  }
}

function del3() {
  if (counter == 2) {
    document.getElementById("img5").style.display = 'none';
    win();
  }
}

function win() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timerem', rem);
  location = 'page2.html';
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. you're crazy knowledgeable man